# Hosting and running azure logic apps locally

Tags: azure-logic-apps

**Is there any way for setting up a local environment for hosting and running azure logic apps locally?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

currently this feature is not available. You can always post **[new ideas](http://aka.ms/logicapps-wish)** that you want to see in the product.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: By the way you can develop the LogicApp locally using the VS2015 extension for LogicApp and deploy it to Azure from VS. let me know if you need pointers.

Comment: @TusharJ is it possible to run some kind of end-to-end tests against a Logic App instance developed in VS _without deploying it to Azure_ though?

Comment: valid request but currently there is no support for this. I see you created a feedback request, sharing it here for future references https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/32354464-provide-an-locally-runnable-sandbox

Answer (score 3):

Logic Apps is updated to run in a new containerized runtime. It can run on Functions, App Service, Kubernetes, Docker and any cloud.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/logic-apps-updated-with-new-hosting-options-improved-performance-and-developer-workflows/